# Sphinx search: Empty attributes with multiple indexes

Tags: php, sphinx

When using the PHP Sphinx client this works:

```
SphinxClient::query ('*', 'index1');
```

But when I try this:

```
SphinxClient::query ('*', 'index1, index2');
```

The result contains no attributes. I'm using Sphinx 2.0.4-release (r3135) and searched the Sphinx forums and google but without any results except this post http://sphinxsearch.com/forum/view.html?id=5141 which didn't help a lot. Anyone here to help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you checked the two indexes to make sure they have the same schema - ie the same attributes?

Comment: I did indeed. Same attributes, same fields. That's what makes it so wierd.

Comment: what type of indexes are they (disk/rt/distributed)? Also does quering just index2 work? And are you using setSelect at all?

Comment: disk, yes and no. I'll try it once again using setSelect.

Comment: never used setSelect before, but it seems you can't query over multiple indexes after sphinx 1.0 or so and get all the columns. setSelect() is the right anwser and I thank you sir! [setSelect documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sphinxclient.setselect.php)

Comment: I'm using both 2.0.1 and 2.0.4 and get attributes on multi-index queries. (using main+delta system)

Comment: I know what you mean but when using Sphinx 0.9 I also got all attributes without using setSelect.